# Не работает функция unique для vector

Tags: stl, vector, c++

почему не удаляются дубликаты из вектора?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

 void printVector(vector<int> & v);

int main() {
    vector<int> v;

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        v.push_back(rand() % 9);
    }

    printVector(v);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << endl;
    printVector(v);
    unique(v.begin(), v.end()); // не работает
    cout << endl;
    printVector(v);

    return 0;
}

void printVector(vector<int> & v){
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
         cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: я отсортировал вроде бы

Comment: Обратите внимание на [возвращаемый тип алгоритма `std::unique`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
v.erase(
    unique(v.begin(), v.end()),
    v.end());
```

Дело в том, что [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) лишь сдвигает дублирующиеся элементы в конец вектора, но не удаляет их оттуда. (Он также возвращает итератор, указывающий на первый из "ненужных" элементов.)

Comment: все ясно большое спасибо

Comment: @perfect: пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, уверены, что для любого **большого** размера вектора и числа дубликатов такая игра с итераторами не грохнется?

Все-таки при realloce даже с уменьшением памяти гарантии от того, что начало не переедет в другой пул адресов никто не дает.

Вообще, итераторы штука опасная.

Comment: @avp: да, `std::unique` гарантированно не вызывает реаллокаций, а после _начала_ `erase` уже всё равно по идее.

Comment: @VladD, да, согласен. По позднему времени путанул.